# LINQ BuildContainsExpression With OR conditions

Tags: linq, frameworks, entity, contains

I'm trying to get the following SQL query to work in LINQ:

```
    Select id from table1 where id in (1,2) or canceledId in (1,2)
```

I'm using BuildContainsExpression to achieve the "IN" condition, but I can't figure out how to implement the "or" condition.
My shot in the dark is as follows:

```
var identifiers = new List<int> {1,2};

var query = (from t in Context.Table1
             select t);

var query =
    query.Where(BuildContainsExpression<Table1, int>(t => t.Id, identifiers));

if (showCanceled)
{
   var expression = query.Where(BuildContainsExpression<Table1, int>(t => t.CanceledId.Value, identifiers)).Expression;
   Expression.Or(expression, transactionsQuery.Expression);
}
```

But I get the following exception:
The binary operator Or is not defined for the types 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Table1]' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Table1]'..

Any ideas? -Am I in the right direction?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: Are you working with Entity Framework in .NET 3.5?

Comment: Yes, (3.5 SP1) sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending your OR in the wrong place. What you are doing now is effectively something like this:

```
(from t in Context.Table1
 where identifiers.Contains(t.Id)
 select t)
OR
(where identifiers.Contains(t.CanceledId))
```

The second problem is that the `BuildContainsExpression` method you use, returns a lambda expression, something that looks like this:

```
t => t.Id == 1 || t.Id == 2 || ...
```

You can't change this expression once it's generated. However, that's what you want because you'd like to have something like this:

```
t => t.Id == 1 || t.Id == 2 || ... || t.CanceledId == 1 || t.CanceledId == 2 || ...
```

You can't simply take the body of this lambda expression and or it together with another expression because it depends on the parameter `t`.

So what you can do is the following:

```
// Overload of BuildContainsExpression.
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildOtherContainsExpression<T>(
    ParameterExpression p, Expression field1, Expression field2, int[] values)
{
    var eq1 = values.Select(v => Expression.Equal(field1, Expression.Constant(v)));
    var eq2 = values.Select(v => Expression.Equal(field2, Expression.Constant(v)));

    var body = eq1.Aggregate((acc, equal) => Expression.Or(acc, equal));
    body = eq2.Aggregate(body, (acc, equal) => Expression.Or(acc, equal));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
}

// Create a parameter expression that represents something of type Table1.
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Table1), "t");

// Create two field expressions that refer to a field of the parameter.
var idField = Expression.Property(parameter, "Id");
var canceledIdField = Expression.Property(parameter, "CanceledId");

// And finally the call to this method.
query.Where(BuildContainsExpression<Table1>(
    parameter, idField, canceledIdField, identifiers));
```

Your if statement would now look like this:

```
if (!showCanceled)
{
    // Use original version of BuildContainsExpression.
}
else
{
    // Create some expressions and use overloaded version of BuildContainsExpression.
}
```

Comment: I'm getting compliation error on the inside where assignment (Expression.Or): Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Table1,bool>>'  

 In addition, the .Expression is not needed since it's already an expression, isn't it?

Comment: You're right and I was a little too soon answering your question. Working on a solution right now..

Comment: Hi, First - thanks for spending the time working on this issue. 
When I try to create the fields of the parameter I get: 
System.ArgumentException: Field 'Id' is not defined for type Table1.
When I check the properties using type reflection, I see 3 properties: Name, NodeType & Type.

Comment: That makes sense, I tested this with a class containing a field but in the real world it's a property. I updated my answer.

Comment: Getting closer...Now I get the following (since CanceledId field is actually nullable):
System.InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'..
I tried to use the "Expression.Convert(idField, typeof(int?))" (saw that somewhere), but did not have any success with it...Any idea?

Comment: Managed to solve that by overriding the CanceledIdField with its Value property: canceledIdField = Expression.Property(canceledIdField, "Value"); Everything works like a charm, Roland - you're the man! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party here - but I think the original code in the original poster's question was 99% right.

The only wrong was that instead of

```
Expression.Or
```

it should have been

```
Expression.OrElse
```